# how to overlay images and still have a responsive site?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a need to overlay some images together and still maintain a responsive site.
I have successfully overlay-ed the required images.  But when I make the browser smaller, the image is not being responsive.. is this because I have used the absolute tag?

any ideas?
[This is the sample site](https://vik-b-it.000webhostapp.com/Test/Test.html)

Comment: honestly why is my question getting voted down? I have an actual question... what is wrong with people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the actual width of the image as a percentage:

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It seems to scale it up, but doesn't scale it down.

Comment: now it seems to work, for some reason my chrome window would not resize.  I restarted chrome and it's fine.  Even without the width of the image it is working.  Thanks